# Is there a TODO.TXT client that allows nesting of tags?

Tags: windows

I am looking to switch to todo.txt from Evernote, and nested tags is a feature that would be hard to live without. Is there a windows tool/client that manages todo.txt file in a way that allows to organize and view nested tags?